# How to let WCF client with BasicHttpSecurityMode.None connect to https service

Tags: wcf, security, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm investigating some issues on existing environment, and i'm a bit confused...

I have one server from where Dynamics CRM plugin consume wcf service. It uses this code to create connection. WCF service is served at https://... address. It works fine on this env.

```
    private static ChannelFactory<IService1> GetChannelFactory()
    {
        var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
            Name = "BasicHttpBinding_IService1",
            Security =
            {
                Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None,
                Transport =
                {
                    ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None,
                    ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None
                }
            }
        };
        var endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress(_serviceUrl);
        return new ChannelFactory<IService1>(myBinding, endPointAddress);
    }
```

When I'm trying to recreate this setup on another environment I get the error during connection to the service. It says  "The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'"
I know that it can be resolved by changing the BasicHttpSecurityMode to Transport, but I need to have the same setup on this environment. How it is possible that the same app requires http address in one case but in other case is able to connect to https. Is there any local setting that I could missed? Is it possible to override hard-coded settings?
What should I check?

Comment: What is your HTTPS address? Is it localhost or an IP?

Comment: None of them, it is normal address resolved by dns.